# How to make int counter go down when answer is wrong

Tags: java, int, counter

Im making a player 2 guesses player 1's number game. Ive made an int counter thats == 10 and is meant to go down everytime player 2 gets answer wrong. I cant get it to work and i need help on how to make this. Youll see what i mean...

```
package guessMain;

import java.awt.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessCodeSource {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("WELCOME TO GUESSING GAME BY JOSH!");
        System.out.println("Rules: Player 1 picks number between 1 - 100 while Player 2 has 10 tries to guess");
        Scanner josh = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name here PLAYER 1: ");
         String p1 = josh.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Enter name here PLAYER 2: ");
         String p2 = josh.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Ok, " +  p2 + " look away. " +  p1 + ", Please enter a number and press enter:");
            int answer = josh.nextInt();
            if (answer >= 100){
                System.out.println("BUSTED! I said a number between 1 - 100!");

            }else if (answer <= 100){       
                System.out.println("Guess in the space below.");
                int guess = josh.nextInt();
                if (guess == answer){
                System.out.println("CORRECT!!!!!");

                }else if (guess != answer);
                     for (int counter = 10; counter-=1);
                    System.out.println("You have " + count + " of guesses left");


            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make reduce a number by one, use the decrement operator.

For example,

```
counter--;
```

would subtract one from the counter.

If you want to subtract more than one, you can use the "-=" operator in the following manner:

```
counter -= 2;
```

So, in your code, in the final else if block, you could change the code to the following to reduce "counter" by 1.

```
else if (guess != answer) {
    counter--;
    System.out.println("You have " + count + " of guesses left");
}
```

But, in your code, you never declare the variable counter. Somewhere, most likely at the top of your code, you want to create this variable. To create an Integer variable you do the following:

```
int counter = 10;
```

You asked how to LOOP as well, so here it is. Read the comments to gain understanding of what the code does. If you have more questions, ask below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("WELCOME TO GUESSING GAME BY JOSH!");
    System.out.println("Rules: Player 1 picks number between 1 - 100 while Player 2 has 10 tries to guess");

    Scanner josh = new Scanner(System.in);

    int guess = 0; // Create these variables up here to access them everywhere in "main"
    int counter = 0;

    boolean continueTheGame = true; // A boolean variable that holds ONLY either true or false

    System.out.println("Enter name here PLAYER 1: ");

    String p1 = josh.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter name here PLAYER 2: ");
    String p2 = josh.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Ok, " +  p2 + " look away. " +  p1 + ", Please enter a number and press enter:");

    int answer = josh.nextInt();

    // A while loop will continue as long as a boolean expression is true.
    // So, we create a boolean variable somewhere above called "continueTheGame"
    // As long as this is true, the code INSIDE of the while loop's brackets will repeat.

    // If the user has less than zero guesses left, we can set the variable to false,
    // which will make the loop stop!

    while (continueTheGame == true) { // The start of the while loop

        if (answer >= 100) {

            System.out.println("BUSTED! I said a number between 1 - 100!");

        } else if (answer <= 100) { 

            System.out.println("Guess in the space below.");
            guess = josh.nextInt();

        }

        if (guess == answer) {
            System.out.println("CORRECT!!!!!");
        } else if (guess != answer) {
            counter--;
            System.out.println("You have " + counter + " of guesses left");

            if (counter > 0) { // If they have MORE than zero guesses left, loop again!
                continueTheGame = true;
            } else { // If they have zero guesses left, make it stop looping
                continueTheGame = false;
            }
        }

    }

    // Once the loop ends, the code will start again here,
    // because the bracket above is the final bracket of the WHILE loop

}
```

Comment: @JoshuaCiantar If this is the correct answer, mark the check-box next to the arrows and number. Thank you. If you have any more questions just ask!

Comment: how then do i make the code go back to the input where you get to guess? When you guess wrong, it says you have 9 guesses left (which is great) but then terminates the program. How to i make it go back to the guessing part? +Connerelsea @Connerelsea

Comment: @JoshuaCiantar You did not mark the check-mark next to the question. I have edited my question to include the answer to your most recent question.

Comment: @JoshuaCiantar I re-formatted your code so it is easier to read, and added comments on the looping part to help you understand what you would need to do to make this loop, so they can guess multiple times.

Comment: OH MY GOSH THANKS SO MUCH!!! You are a genius. Makes so much sense! Thanks for all your help. XD

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here is the full functional main method you are looking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
            System.out.println("WELCOME TO GUESSING GAME BY JOSH!");
            System.out.println("Rules: Player 1 picks number between 1 - 100 while Player 2 has 10 tries to guess");
            Scanner josh = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter name here PLAYER 1: ");
             String p1 = josh.nextLine();
             System.out.println("Enter name here PLAYER 2: ");
             String p2 = josh.nextLine();
             System.out.println("Ok, " +  p2 + " look away. " +  p1 + ", Please enter a number and press enter:");
                int answer = josh.nextInt();
                if (answer >= 100){
                    System.out.println("BUSTED! I said a number between 1 - 100!");

                }else {       
                    System.out.println("Guess in the space below.");

                    }
                      for (int count = 10; count>=0; count--) {
                          int guess = josh.nextInt();
                          if (guess == answer){
                              System.out.println("CORRECT!!!!!");
                              System.exit(0);
                          } else {
                        System.out.println("You have " + count + " of guesses left");
                        if (count == 0) {
                            System.out.println("Sorry, you lost, no more tries..");
                            System.exit(0);
                        } 

                      }

                    }


          josh.close();      
        }
```

Comment: thank you, i needed to learn that you can do i++ as well as i--. Thx again